# How do I access pixel values from a raspberry pi camera?

Tags: python-3, pixel, picamera

I am writing an AI program in Python on a raspberry pi, where I need to access raw individual pixel values from a raspberry pi camera.  I really don't want to save the picture, I want to process the raw pixel information from one pixel to the next.

Comment: How is the image data stored? What module are you using to load/capture the image? The way to access pixel RGB values varies according to the datatype.

Comment: I am using a raspberry pi 3 B+.  The datatype I would like to use is RGB.  I am hoping I don't have to store the image data.

Comment: There isn't any known way (that I could find) to access the Pi Camera's data before it saves, however [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/65919/33979) talks about making a RAM disk and saving the image to that, so it's never truly saved in storage.